# Extrinsic and intrinsic properties

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I'm reading Weeks' *The Shape of Space*. He mentions of intrinsic and extrinsic geometry and topology of surfaces (two-dimensional manifolds) in a vague but intuitive way.

Would it be correct to say that a change in intrinsic topology/geometry implies a change in extrinsic?

Also would a distinct extrinsic topology imply district extrinsic geometry?

Answer (score 1):

By the extent to which I understand things,

(1) An *intrinsic property* is a property of the object itself, whereas an *extrinsic property* is a relation between the objects and other objects. This applies to other concepts, e.g. the number $2$ is even, eveness is an intrinsic property; the number $2$ is less than the number $3$, inferiority is an extrinsic property. Similarly, given a topological space $X$, $X$ must be either compact or non-compact, whereas we can only say $X$ is close/open assuming implicitly that $X$ is a subspace of another space $Y$.

(2) It depends on the nature the change. $2$ is even. If we plus it by $1$, it becomes odd, but it remains less than $5$.

(3) Geometry contains generally finer structure than topology. But I don't think there is any relation between the pair (intrinsic,extrinsic) and the pair (geometry, topology).

Comment: When considering $X$ as a topological space, $X$ is always both open and closed, by the topology axioms. However as subset of a larger topological space, it might not be. In other words, you mean the right thing, but formulated it wrong.

Comment: In the case Y=X, then yes, X is both a open and a close subspace of itself.

Comment: Even if $X\ne Y$, and $X$ is not an open subset of $Y$, then $X$ is *still* an open subset in the subspace topology of $X$,

Comment: What you are saying is just my answer applied to the case $Y=X$. And I totally agree with you by the way. I’m just adding a bit of my point of view.

Comment: I explicitly spoke of the case $Y$ *not equal to* $X$. For example, be $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=[0,1]$. Clearly $Y$ is not open in $X$ (a closed interval is not open in $\mathbb R$), yet $Y$ is still open in the subspace topology of $Y$. That is, in the subspace topology of $[0,1]$, the set $[0,1]$ *is* an open set.

Comment: What you say is true.